# Python-Modelica interface: Data

Tags: python, modelica

what is in your opinion the best way to get data (measure date for example) into modelica (dymola)? Is it possible, to import data from python to modelica (for example into a combi-time-table)?
My idea would be as follows:

1. pre processing of measured data in python
2. load the data from python into modelica (comi-time-table)
3. rund simulation studies (scripted in python)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

That's probably a matter of opinion. But since you have to do much of your data post- and preprocessing in Python I would definitely export my (plant) model from Dymola as a co-simulation FMU and run it in Python.

In Dymola you can export FMU's and 'execute' them **on the same pc** that holds the Dymola license file. If you need to run the FMU on another pc you'll have to buy a special binary export license.

There is a free Python package called PyFMI ([www.pyfmi.org](http://www.pyfmi.org)) which makes it easy to run an FMU in Python. See the examples at [http://www.jmodelica.org/page/4924](http://www.jmodelica.org/assimulo_home/pyfmi_1.0/examples.html).

PyFMI can be a bit tricky to get up and running (with the right Python package dependencies and so on). So if you are not an experienced Python user I would suggest that you download the installer for [JModelica.org](http://www.jmodelica.org/binary) which will do much the setting up for you.

Best regards,

Rene Just Nielsen

Answer (score 0):

As Rene Just Nielsen pointed out, this is primarily opinion based.

To give another way of accomplishing your goal, try the `DymolaInterface`. You could either set the table-parameter via the Interface in python, our use a .txt-file which you create and alter in python, and Modelica just knows the path to the file. The interface comes with your Dymola installation under `Modelica\Library\python_interface\dymola.egg` where you will also find documentation for the functions.

Another python-package for using FMU's is [FMPy](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy). I image both `FMPy` and `PyFMI` have their pros and cons.

The last option which does not require any external python package would be to use mos-files to execute simulations and use the .txt-files to read in the data. If the task you described is the only thing you want to accomplish, mos-scripts are quite sufficient.